# How to connect bigquery using php programming?

Tags: php, google-bigquery

I have set up as per the below guidelines - https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/create-simple-app-api#bigquery-simple-app-local-dev-php

I tried to run the php files but did not understand how i proceed or do I need to write a php function to call or can I use existing php file under bigquery ?

Can anyone help me to run simple query or if you have already tried to connect the bigquery please share?

Comment: What you are asking is unclear. Could you elaborate a bit more on what you intend to do or have problems with?

Comment: I need to connect bigquery db via PHP programming. This will help me to get the data from bigquery via PHP script.

I checked on google and found some sources to connect big query (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/create-simple-app-api#bigquery-simple-app-local-dev-php)

PHP version - PHP 5.3.29 (do the bigquery support ?)

I tried with this but could not able to do this. if you suggest me to how to do it would be helpful